# How to test a password reset mailer with Capybara and Minitest in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, minitest, clearance

I'm using the Clearance gem in Rails along with Capybara and Minitest and I can't figure out how to test the password reset mailer. I'm not trying to test the Clearance gem, which is already well-tested, but I'd like a high-level integration test to ensure the expected user experience doesn't break, and that includes the mailer.

Here's the test that I can't complete (/integration/password_reset_test.rb):

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user   = create(:user)
  end

  test "User can reset their password" do
    visit "/login"
    assert page.current_path == "/login"
    click_link "Forgot password?"
    assert page.current_path == "/passwords/new"
    assert_selector "h1", text: "Reset your password"
    fill_in("Email", :with => @user.email)
    click_button "Reset your password"
    assert page.current_path == "/passwords"
    assert_selector "h1", text: "Your password reset email is on the way."
    # This is where I'm stuck
    # Would like to test that the correct email was sent by checking
    #      basic content in the email and then simulate a user clicking
    #      the password reset link and then updating their password.
  end
end
```

How do you actually test that the mail was sent properly and is there a way to simulate capybara clicking through the password reset link in the email and then filling out the form to reset the password?

I tried this as well, but this line failed, so I'm clearly not doing something right:

```
assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
```

I can test manually by grabbing the password reset email link from the server logs, so the feature is working properly.

All of the examples I can find online are assuming you're using Rspec, but nothing for Minitest. I also tried using the [capybara-email gem](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/capybara-email), but that did not have Minitest examples and I couldn't get that working either.

For reference:
[Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/17ec4598a6512043799b3c9bda6fdcb2)
[test_helper.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/6bf935304981ccecb9f986207fa74de7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you want to do `capybara-email` is a good choice.  To set it up you would include it either into `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` or into the individual test class where it's needed (in your current case - `PasswordResetTest`).  You, most likely, also need to configure ActiveJob to perform jobs when they are queued rather than delaying them (otherwise the emails won't actually be sent). One way to do that is by including `ActiveJob::TestHelper` and then using the `perform_enqueued_jobs` method it provided. That leads to something along the lines of

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::Email::DSL
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  def setup
    clear_emails
    @user   = create(:user)
  end

  test "User can reset their password" do
    perform_enqueued_jobs do
      visit "/login"
      assert_current_path("/login")
      click_link "Forgot password?"
      assert_current_path("/passwords/new")
      assert_selector "h1", text: "Reset your password"
      fill_in("Email", :with => @user.email)
      click_button "Reset your password"
      assert_current_path("/passwords")
      assert_selector "h1", text: "Your password reset email is on the way."
    end
    open_email(@user.email)
    assert_content(current_email, 'blah blah')
    current_email.click_link('Reset Password')
    assert_current_path(reset_password_path)
    ...  # fill out form with new password, etc.
  end
end
```

Note the use of `assert_current_path` rather than `assert page.current_path...` -  You generally want to prefer the former since the latter has no waiting/retrying behavior and can lead to flaky tests.  Also note that writing tests that hardcode in the path names leads to a nightmare if you ever want to change the path names so you might be better off writing your codes using the rails provided routes helpers instead

```
assert_current_path(login_path)
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! Lots of helpful tips in here. I was missing `include ActiveJob::TestHelper` and `perform_enqueued_jobs` with that `capybara-email` is working great.

Comment: Regarding hardcoding path names, I was thinking that you would want to test that the urls in the browser were working properly. I think of the url as part of the user interface, so it makes sense to me to test that `/login` is the intended url, since Clearance uses `sign_in_path` but I want the button names and urls to use `login`. Is this a bad approach? Is it just bad because it makes the tests brittle?

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly It leads to brittle tests and unless it's a url users have to remember I would argue it's not really part of the UI either (Safari actually hides the path part of the url by default).  If you really want to test for specific paths or have requirements for specific ones (a published API for instance) I'd add one or more tests that are just a bunch of `assert sign_in_path == '/login' ` etc. So they're all checked in one place, and then use the helpers in your tests.  That way if you ever need to change '/sign_up' to '/join_us' it's only one test you have to change.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense